# MonoTouch: Is less memory allowed on ipad 3 than ipad 2 per process?

Tags: ipad, memory, xamarin.ios

I have an application that works just fine on ipad 2, on ipad 3 it crashes, apparently because of an out of memory error.  Is it possible they cut down how much a single application can use?  If so, is there a good way with monotouch to trace this on the device so I can best adjust what is needed?

Comment: Each label that you render in your application needs to create some backing store in the form of a CALayer which holds the data to the RGB buffer for the image.   It is possible that you just have too many of those in memory.

Comment: mig: this very well is the issue, however my concern is why the heck ipad2 works flawlessly while ipad3, with more resurces, would not.  As below its likely due to the retina display which I read now multiple times takes 4x as much ram to process a single thing?  I have about 15 views i load into memory on start, and 5 of them have data grids i build by hand on search, so i can easily see how this is memory insense.  Though i would have never imagined it would crash an ipad 3 and not 2 when 3 has more resources.  this is proven by being a display only issue cause creating the views cause

Comment: no issue, but if i add them to my visible subview that is when it crashes.  i even broke it down to specific items, and i went from making a label 255 pixels wide to 120 pixels wide and that fixes it.  Its surely a memory issue however i just didnt get how a ipad 3 could possibly handle less than an ipad 2, both with no other apps loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that since screen resolution has changed, you'll need 4x as many bits while rendering to the screen or when using images.

There are basically two tools to track down memory problems:

- Instruments. This is an Apple tool/profiler that does a lot of things, amongst others it can do memory profiling. You can open it from Xcode (menu Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments).
- [HeapShot](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MONOTOUCH_PROFILER). This is a memory profiler for MonoTouch - you can access it in MonoDevelop (menu Project -> Profile - Mono). If the problem is image data, it will not show up directly with this tool, since it only tracks managed objects (and the image data is stored in the corresponding native peer, so the HeapShot profiler doesn't see it. You can however see the number of images you're using and if you're leaking any of them).

Comment: I am aware of instruments, just not sure if it works in monoTouch.  I will try that out though.  All my crashing appears to be on rendering of my views, and only if i add a item to a subview.  creating it in memory has no effect, so this 4x possible is the reason.  I appreciate that!

Comment: also my problem is not images, its when i render a bunch of labels to fill a grid that this is happening.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.  I had all subviews added to my main view on start so they were all rending even though not visible.  Changed it so they only are in the main view when needed and it fixed it! Thanks again